# Close ruby tag for form_for

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm newbie of Ruby on rails.

As I know, this Ruby tag <%= %> used when you call or print a function. only.

But when I use `form_for`, the IDE ask me to add `<% end %>`

```
<%= form_for(@article, :html => {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'}) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :title %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Title of article', autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
        <%= f.label :description %>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <%= f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Body of article', autofocus: true %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
      </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

What I expect is:

```
<% form_fo %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **What I expect is not using close ruby tag**?

Comment: Just edit question @Pavan

Comment: Its still not clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I expect is:
>
> ```
> <% form_for %>
> ...
> <% end %>
> ```

Your expectation is somewhat understandable, but wrong.

1. Each `form_for` needs a matching `end`.
2. And if you don't use `<%=` on form_for, then it won't be printed. Will still be generated and all, but you won't see it.

You could try another markup language, like HAML, for example. It doesn't require you to close most anything (because it relies on indentation to derive info about code structure)

```
= form_for ... do |f|
  = f.label ...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Sergio, HAML is an alternative to the regular .erb style and so is SLIM.

SLIM would allow you to write that piece of code as:

```
= form_for(@article, :html => {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'}) do |f|
  .form-group
    .control-label.col-sm-2
      = f.label :title

    .col-sm-8
      = f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Title of article', autofocus: true

  .form-group
    .control-label.col-sm-2
      = f.label :description

    .col-sm-8
      = f.text_area :description, rows: 10, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Body of article', autofocus: true

  .form-group
    .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
      = f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg'
```

You can omit completely the `div` by writing `.something` (which will render `<div class="something">` and equals `div.something`) or `#something` (the same but with an id). And you can mention html tags simply like `h2#main-header` (which renders `<h2 id="main-header">`)

If you wanted to use a conditional you would:

```
- if something
  h1= "#{current_user.name} is here"
- else
  p Oops
```

If you want to execute a block without printing the block return itself, but just things inside the block:

```
- ['chachacha','chuchuchu'].each_with_index do |thing, i|
  p= i == 0 ? 'Chachacha is not chuchuchu' : 'Chuchuchu is not chachacha'
```

This would render:

```
<p>Chachacha is not chuchuchu</p>
<p>Chuchuchu is not chachacha</p>
```

It has a whole bunch of stuff and I found it to really slim down the view code and make it much more perceptible. IT also has the added benefit that you can simply copy the markup and use it straight away inside jquery as selectors, or a least see them in similar ways.

Either way I found both HAML and SLIM better suited than plain .erb once you understand the .erb templating system.

Answer (score 1):

Only the opening tag has the = to show whether it should be printed or not.
The end statement does not need to be printed.
Hope that helps!